# CarrierWave and Fog, S3 bucket and store_dir configuration

Tags: configuration, amazon-s3, carrierwave, ruby-on-rails-3.2, fog

I'm trying to figure out how to setup CarrierWave to work with Fog and Amazon S3. On S3, I have a bucket, "bucket1" with folder "images". Uploads work fine. For example, an image might get uploaded to something of the form https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket1/images/picture/pic1.jpg. However, in the show view, when I call the image_url helper, I get https://s3.amazonaws.com/images/picture/pic1.jpg. What am I missing here?

```
#config/initializers/carrierwave.rb
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',
    :aws_access_key_id      => 'aws_key',
    :aws_secret_access_key  => 'aws_secret'
  }
  config.fog_directory  = 'bucket1'
  config.fog_host       = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com'
  config.fog_public     = true
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'}
end

#app/uploader/image_uploader.rb
def store_dir
  "images/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}"
end

#app/views/pictures/show.html.erb
<%= image_tag @picture.image_url if @picture.image? %>
```

Comment: are you hosting it on heroku?

Comment: I'm hosting it own via HostGator(dev) & EC2 (prod)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing the

config.fog_host       = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com'

configuration and instead put

storage :fog

in your uploader. It might be overriding the actual path with the one you're providing.

Comment: I had both configurations before. My fix was just to remove the fog_host. Now it uploads to https://bucket1.s3.amazonaws.com/images/picture/image_name.jpg. Which works just fine!

Answer (score 1):

Although not directly germane to this particular question, it feel that the following information is both related and helpful.

If you are using non-public links in S3, you can control the TTL of those links with the `fog_authenticated_url_expiration` configuration parameter:

```
...
config.fog_public = false
config.fog_authenticated_url_expiration = 600 # 10 minutes
...
```